# Django не видит статический файл

Tags: python, django, static

Я сделал в папке templates файл layout.html для главного шаблона страницы:

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'layout.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

И также я создал папку static в корневом разделе (не в приложении) и хочу, чтобы layout.css применялся ко всем шаблонам, но Django почему-то не видит его.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    BASE_DIR / '/static/'
]
```

Структура проекта:

```
├───home
├───account
├───site
├───static
    └───layout.css
├───templates
    └───layout.html
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не STATICFILES_DIR, а STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: Не помогло. Джанго ругается теперь: 

`(staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:\static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.`

Comment: Ну значит проверяйте ваш BASE_DIR

Comment: BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

Comment: Если печатаю BASE_DIR, то все хорошо, если печатаю BASE_DIR / '/static/', то выводится C:\static

Comment: Ах да, слэши-то уберите - `'static'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Для дополнительных директорий со статическими файлами используется `STATICFILES_DIRS`, а **не** `STATICFILES_DIR`.
- Чтобы статические файлы искались не в корневой директории, а в папке static в директории проекта Django, нужно использовать `BASE_DIR / "static/"` или `BASE_DIR / "static"`, но **не** `BASE_DIR / "/static/"`.

**settings.py**:

```py
...

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]

...
```